# access all split strings in XSLT at once

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am splitting comma separated string as follows:

```
<xsl:call-template name="SimpleStringLoop">
    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="'1,2,3,4,'"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="SimpleStringLoop">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($input) &gt; 0">
      <xsl:variable name="v" select="substring-before($input, ',')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$v"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="SimpleStringLoop">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, ',')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>
```

How do I access all extracted values like in an array?
I need to access each and all of them and use them in a xslt filtering.
When the SimpleStringLoop is called, $v holds value 1 the first time, another time it holds 2 and so on. But is there a way to make use of $v like using index in arrays like $v[1], $v[2]

so i have `$v[1]=1, $v[2] =2 etc..`

OR am I so dumb that I am not even understanding this recursive process at all??

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Unfortunately XSLT 1.0..

Comment: XSLT variables are immutable and there isn't an array function. Maybe if you can explain what you are trying to do with the template we might be able to provide a better work around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Michael Kay says, XSLT 2.0 would be your friend here, as it can handle sequences easily. In fact, you would not even need a recursive template, because you could use the handy tokenize function to split your string

```
<xsl:variable name="fields" select="tokenize($input, ',')" />
```

Then, for example, to get the second field you could just do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="$fields[2]"/>
```

But if you are stuck with XSLT 1.0 you are going to do some extra work. At the moment, all your recursive template is doing is outputting a series of characters. These form part of the result tree, so XSLT would not be able to access them initially. What you need to do at this point though, is output elements instead.

```
  <xsl:variable name="v" select="substring-before($input, ',')"/>
  <field>
    <xsl:value-of select="$v"/>
  </field>
```

Next, you need to wrap your existing **xsl:call-template** in a variable, so you can then start to access the results of the template call.

```
<xsl:variable name="fields">
  <xsl:call-template name="SimpleStringLoop">
    <xsl:with-param name="input" select="'1,2,3,4,'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Now currently, the **fields** variable holds a 'result tree fragment' at this point, but you want to be able to access the nodes within it. This is where the extension function comes in. There is an extension that can convert a result tree fragment to a node-set, so you can use XSLT functions on it. This very much depends on the processor as to what namespace you use, but ultimately it would allow you to write something like this:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="msxml:node-set($fields)/field[2]"/>
```

Try this XSLT as an example. Note, I am using Mircosoft's XSLT processor here. Other XSLT processors are available....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxml">
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="fields">
      <xsl:call-template name="SimpleStringLoop">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="'1,2,3,4,'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="msxml:node-set($fields)/field[2]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="SimpleStringLoop">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($input) &gt; 0">
      <xsl:variable name="v" select="substring-before($input, ',')"/>
      <field>
        <xsl:value-of select="$v"/>
      </field>
      <xsl:call-template name="SimpleStringLoop">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, ',')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For more information on node-sets, try this link as a start:

http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! Best explained!

Answer (score 2):

You need XSLT 2.0. In XSLT 1.0 there is no data type to handle a sequence of strings. You can create a node-set containing the strings in a variable, and if you have the exslt:node-set() extension then you can process the node-set, but it's a poor substitute. Time to upgrade.